# How to filter numeric values in a table using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to highlight the row of a table in yellow if the data in the 3rd column is above or equal to 100, and remove the row if it's below 20. The table looks something like this:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Animal</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cat</td>
        <td>Purple</td>
        <td>17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Dog</td>
        <td>Orange</td>
        <td>236</td>
    </tr>
    … etc.
</table>
```

This is what I have so far, which doesn't seem to be working:

```js
$("table tr td:nth-child(3)").filter(function() {
   return (this.text() >= 100);}).parent().css("background", "yellow");
```

I think I'm missing some syntax, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change text to innerText

```
$("table tr td:nth-child(3)").filter(function() {
    return (this.innerText >= 100);}).parent().css("background", "yellow");
```